# Finding the Associated Eigenvector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvector, eigenvalue

For this problem, I think I got most of code correct. However, the correct eigenvector contains the negative values of what I have.

The instructions:

[image]

My code:

```
clear all; close all;

M = [0 1/4 1/4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   1/2 0 1/4 1/4 1/6 0 0 0 0 0; 
   1/2 1/4 0 0 1/6 1/4 0 0 0 0; 
   0 1/4 0 0 1/6 0 1/2 1/4 0 0; 
   0 1/4 1/4 1/4 0 1/4 0 1/4 1/4 0; 
   0 0 1/4 0 1/6 0 0 0 1/4 1/2; 
   0 0 0 1/4 0 0 0 1/4 0 0; 
   0 0 0 1/4 1/6 0 1/2 0 1/4 0; 
   0 0 0 0 1/6 1/4 0 1/4 0 1/2; 
   0 0 0 0 0 1/4 0 0 1/4 0];

[Y, Z] = eig(M) % pull the first column of T

A8 = Y(:,1) % P

M*A8 % check

save ('A8.dat', 'A8', '-ascii')
```

I use,

```
[Y, Z] = eig(M)
```

to find the associated eigenvalue of 1 in Z with its associated eigenvector from Y. This yields P (or A8) to be:

```
0.1667
0.3333
0.3333
0.3333
0.5000
0.3333
0.1667
0.3333
0.3333
0.1667
```

And when I multiply M by P, I get P, which checks out. Apparently the proper values should be negative values of what I got. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is correct. To understand the reason, we need to look at the definition of eigenvectors (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)):

> An eigenvector or characteristic vector of a square matrix A is a non-zero vector v that, when multiplied with A, yields a scalar multiple of itself. [...] That is: **Av = nv**.

where **v** is the eigenvector and **n** is the corresponding eigenvalue.

As these are linear operations, **A*(kv)=n*(kv)** for any non-zero, scalar **k**. That means, an eigenvector multiplied by a factor **k** will be another eigenvector to the corresponding eigenvalue.

Matlab outputs normalized eigenvectors, i.e. their length (`norm(A8)`) equals 1. But still, both the positive and the negative version are eigenvectors of `M`. You can verify this by creating the negative version of your result and multiplying it with P, which will again give you the negative version of your result.